# Print rows and columns alternately in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java

I have the below code for printing a two-dimensional array. I would like to print rows and columns in this array alternately.

```
public class TwoDimensionalArrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int marks[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    for(int j=0;j<marks[0].length;j++) {
        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++) {

        }

    }
}
```

This is how I'd like my output to look.

```
1 2 3
1 4 7
5 6
5 8
9
```

How can I tackle this?

Comment: What does the above not achieve that you'd like it to?

Comment: Some of the values in your expected output don't exist in the array - where are they coming from?

Comment: Oops. Editing my post.

Comment: Still dont have the 4 and 8 on your code...

Comment: I edited. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The key is setting `i = j` in the nested for loops

```
for (int j = 0; j < marks.length; j++) {
    for (int i = j; i < marks[j].length; i++) {
        System.out.print(marks[j][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    if (j == marks.length - 1)
        break;
    for (int i = j; i < marks.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(marks[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that will print what you need. Please be aware that you might need to do something with that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    for(int j=0;j<marks[0].length;j++) {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++) {
            try {
                System.out.print(marks[j][i+j]);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++) {
            try {
                if(j < marks.length-1) {
                    System.out.print(marks[i + j][j]);
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Lots of confusing i's and j's, but it outputs what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int marks[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    for(int j = 0; j < marks[0].length; j++) 
    {
        //Row across
        for(int i = j; i < marks.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(marks[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        //Column down
        if (j != marks[0].length - 1) //so we don't print 9 twice
        {
            for(int i = j; i < marks.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(marks[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```